# Percentage Function PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am little confused about calculating the percentage. I want to know how I'm going to compute the percentage to find the answer percentage also.

I have array values:

```
$week1_1 = 93.0;
$week1_2 = 0.0;
$week2_1 = 100.0;
$week2_2 = 0.0;
$week3_1 = 100.0;
$week3_2 = 0.0;
$week4_1 = 100.0;
$week4_2 = 0.0;

$arr_week_ave = array();
$arr_week_ave[] = $week1_1;
$arr_week_ave[] = $week1_2;
$arr_week_ave[] = $week2_1;
$arr_week_ave[] = $week2_2;
$arr_week_ave[] = $week3_1;
$arr_week_ave[] = $week3_2;
$arr_week_ave[] = $week4_1;
$arr_week_ave[] = $week4_2;

$ave = ROUND(((array_sum($arr_values) / count($arr_week_ave)) * 100), 2);

echo $ave;
```

then I'll divide it to 4 times to 100.. but the answer is 4715 . The answer is wrong, I want it to be 98.7..

Can someone help about this case?

Comment: `(array_sum($myArray) / (count($myArray) * 100)) * 100`

Comment: @MarkBaker I think the *real* problem is more fundamental.

Comment: Uhm. Are you wanting the **average** ?? Why are you calling it percentage ?

Comment: Hi it not suites on the answer. it became 4715000.. huhuhu..

Comment: YES. I want to average it to percentage also. like 98.7% . NL-X

Comment: @beautifulzxz then remove the `* 100`. The code you have already returns `9872.5`

Comment: @beautifulzxz show us you entire code. Especially the part where you do the `echo`.

Comment: ok sir wait ill edit my post

Comment: hi nl-x i updated my post

Comment: Does this have some bearing on mysql?

Comment: yes. but for more clarification, i set value on each array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't want the sum of the numbers in the array but rather the average? Php has n inbuilt function for calculating the sum but for the average you need to create your own function which can be done as follows:

```
<?php
function avrg()
{
 $count = func_num_args();
 $args = func_get_args();
 return (array_sum($args) / $count);
}
?>
```

Here the func_num_args() function gets the number of arguments passed and adds them by placing them in an array and then dividing them by no. of arguments, if you simply call this function like this:

```
avrg(94.9, 100, 100, 100);
```

Then you will get 98.7, please choose this as the correct answer if it solves your doubt by clicking on the tick symbol to the left.

Comment: i will try this. thanks. please keep in touch, wait for my other response.

Comment: @beautifulzxz please do tell me if it works or not, otherwise there may be a problem further up the code, we will solve that then! :)

Comment: hi it returned 0 on your code. and i'd still find what's wrong

Comment: Can you please post the entire file? Because i think there is something wrong further up your code. I tested it in codepad, check this [link](http://codepad.org/nu15NLOS), it works just fine.

Comment: hello. i pasted it all. actually i am getting files on mysql. but for more clarification, i set a value.

Comment: i found that the count it returned is 8, how do i get only 4 because there's only four value on array.

Comment: Listen you have added 0.0, four times to the array thats why the count of elements becomes 8, see even though 0 does not hold a value it does count as an element, thus do not push those elements that are zero into an array as this way its dividing 393/8, so i've modified your code as follows, [link](http://codepad.org/D1GajNhi)

Comment: hello , why array values returned 8 even i have only 4 values.. does the array count all array? not their values inside?

Comment: Yes, the array function counts all the array values whether they are 0 or not does not make a difference, glad your doubt could be solved!

Comment: how I will return only 4 count values of array? help me coz im freakin me out of my mind haha thanks

Comment: when i used the array_count_values, it returns an error.

Comment: Just use count($arrayName) :)

Comment: it returned 8 counts, for example is what i posted few mins ago, the count values that array returned is 8. but i need 4 counts only because there are 4 value in array. it gives lower than 50% answer.

Comment: i cannot remove the other array because i get values from database

Answer (score 1):

```
check this

<?php

$new = array( 94.9, 100, 100, 100 );

echo array_sum($new)/count($new);

?>
```

Comment: hello. IT results less than the 4715. i got 12.5 answer on this formula.

Comment: I want to average it to percentage also. like 98.7%  .. I searched for almost 3hrs, but i cant find the best answer......

Comment: In what sense can you get 4715? http://codepad.org/ws8O4an8

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(array_sum($myArray) / (count($myArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the average, remove the `* 100`. The average is always calculated by taking the sum of the values divided by the number of values you have. (And don't multiply or divide by 100 as you would do to calculate a percentage of something. Because you simply want the average.)

```
$ave = ROUND(array_sum($arr_values) / count($arr_values), 1);
```

The code you have already returns `9872.5`. But you want 98.7.
(Your code does not return `4715` as you state in your question. I just tried it.)

Comment: hi nl-x , yeah you're right i looked at my code. i double checked and it return 9872.5.. thanks

Comment: @beautifulzxz so your problem is solved now? (If so, please mark the answer as accepted to mark the question as resolved. You can do this by clicking on the check mark next to the answer that you selected.)

Comment: hi nl-x i updated my post